# Inserir elemento html "div" com javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como posso inserir uma div de acordo com sua classe ou id?

Exemplificação

```
<div id="main"> </div>
<div id="about"> </div>
<div id="more"> </div>
```

Elas estanciadas em um único arquivo! E então com uma função javascript consigo 
inserir a div na página!

Muito Obrigado, espero ter sido claro!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o método `load()`, para carregar o arquivo, nesse arquivo as divs poderiam ter a tag `hidden='true'`

Logo após você carregar o arquivo, basta pegar a id da div carregada, e dar um `show()`, ou remover a tag `hidden` da que você escolheu! Este é um método (acredito eu) bem mais alternativo, não sei se existe um mais simplificado para isso.

Comment: Essa resolução é perfeita muito obrigado!

Comment: kkkkk de nada, kkkk

Comment: @HectorGabrielGarcia marque a resposta como resolvida para que sua dúvida possa ajudar outros usuários.

Answer (score 0):

Na minha opinião não é necessário utilizar jQuery ou XHR para realizar este feito, pois você pode carregar os arquivos como resources no header do html.

Desta forma carregue os arquivos no header de seu HTML:

```
<script src="about.txt"></script>
<script src="main.txt"></script>
<script src="more.txt"></script>
```

No corpo destes arquivos declare o conteúdo como uma variável:

> about.txt

```
var about = '<div class=about> </div>';
```

> main.txt

```
var main = '<div class=main> </div>';
```

> more.txt

```
var more = '<div class=more> </div>';
```

E então ao carregar a página, os recursos que você carregou em forma de arquivos de texto serão disponíveis em nível de variável para utiliza-los, assim você pode manipular eles à vontade.

Exemplo (após incluir os arquivos):

```
console.log(main+about+more);
document.body.innerHTML = main+about+more;
```